# Use "screen" with a display

Tags: matlab, unix, x11, display, gnu-screen

I'm using Matlab on a Unix server and would like to be able to keep a session opened (with Matlab windows still displayed) on a screen so that I can get back to it whenever I want.

One solution I found that may work is using "altscreen" and set it on "on".

But I'm not really sure how to proceed with it and how to properly call the function. Is it even the right way?

If anyone could give me some advice that'd be amazing!

Comment: I wouldn't recommend doing so because usually the ssh connexion might get interreputed even for a few seconds which causes the window to close and the code lost. I prefer using screen and using the `-logfile` option to track progress.

Comment: Hi Marouen! Thanks for your answer.
I'm actually using screens so that I can lose ssh connection, I'm using Matlab on a remote computer and use screens to run overnight simulations.
What is the most efficient way of using logfiles to go back to wherever you were on previous sessions?

Answer (score 1):

you can create a new screen using `screen -R myscreen` then launch matlab using `matlab -nodesktop -nosplash -r myscript -logfile log.out` (without .m in myscript) .

The `-nodesktop -nosplash` option allows you to launch matlab without the GUI,
then you can close the screen with `CTRL+A+D`.

you can check the progress on the log file without connecting to the screen.

If you want to connect back to the screen use `screen -R myscreen`

Comment: Hi! Thanks again for your answer! I thought about this solution but I need to use Simulink too which is impossible without any GUI. The idea really was to try to store the GUI state and restore it when connecting back to the screen.

Do you know if it is possible to turn on/off the GUI for Matlab when already launched?

Comment: nothing crosses my mind now, though I am pretty sure that you can write in code what you are doing in simulink GUI.